# Trying to upload image, getting error: this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Tags: android, image, http, post

I am trying to upload a simple image that the user chooses from the file manager on the phone.

The upload is attempted in onActivityResult and crashes with the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

I tried to add the permission the following way:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
```

The full code:

```
package com.example.mobiware.ivaapp.Activities;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mobiware.ivaapp.Api.AppMethods;
import com.example.mobiware.ivaapp.Objects.User;
import com.example.mobiware.ivaapp.R;
import com.example.mobiware.ivaapp.config.AppConfig;
import com.example.mobiware.ivaapp.database.SQLiteHandler;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


//Image request code
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

//storage permission code
private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

//Bitmap to get image from gallery
private Bitmap bitmap;

//Uri to store the image uri
private Uri filePath;
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final String TAG = "register";
EditText firstName;
EditText lastName;
EditText email;
EditText password;
Button Register;
CircleImageView UserPhoto;
com.example.mobiware.ivaapp.Api.AppMethods AppMethods;
private SQLiteHandler db;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
String defaultPath = "userimages";
boolean photo = false;
Uri mImageUri;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
Uri photoURI;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    AppMethods = new AppMethods(getApplicationContext());

    //Requesting storage permission
    requestStoragePermission();

    UserPhoto = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    UserPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        public void onClick(View v) {

           showFileChooser();

        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (firstName.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                firstName.setError("Vazio");
            } else if (lastName.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                lastName.setError("Vazio");
            } else if (email.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                email.setError("Vazio");
            } else if (password.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                password.setError("Vazio");
            } else {
                boolean social = false;
                User User = new User();

                User.setFirstName(firstName.getText().toString());
                User.setLastName(lastName.getText().toString());
                User.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                User.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
                // User.setAvatar(String.valueOf(getStringImage(bitmap)));
                AppMethods.insertNewUser(social, User);
            }
        }
    });
}



 /*
   * This is the method responsible for image upload
   * We need the full image path and the name for the image in this method
   * */
public void uploadMultipart() {
    //getting name for the image

    //getting the actual path of the image
    String path = getPath(filePath);

    //Uploading code
    try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, AppConfig.Avatar)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                .addParameter("name", "userpic") //Adding text parameter to the request
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


//method to show file chooser
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

//handling the image chooser activity result
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            UserPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    uploadMultipart();
}

//method to get the file path from uri
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}


//Requesting permission
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }
    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}


//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Full logcat:**

```
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:1459)
                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:20913)
                                                at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:3871)
                                                at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.resolveCallingUserIdEnforcingPermissionsLocked(SettingsProvider.java:1750)
                                                at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.getSystemSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1243)
                                                at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:430)
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:404)
                                                at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:283)
                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Comment: "I am trying to upload a simple image that the user chooses from the file manager on the phone" -- `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has nothing to do with a "file manager". "The upload is attempted in onActivityResult and crashes with the error" -- please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace, not just the error message. If I had to guess, your problem comes from `getPath()`, which will not work for most `Uri` values returned by `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: edited, any fix you may have ?

Comment: That stack trace does not seem to be coming from your app. What evidence do you have that this is coming from your process?

Comment: It only shows when i set "No Filters" on logcat, but the errors comes exactly when the image fails to upload.

Comment: Make sure that `MultipartUploadRequest` is not attempting to do network I/O on the main application thread. Also, get rid of `getPath()`. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Given the API for `MultipartUploadRequest`, you will need to use that `InputStream` and a `FileOutputStream` on a file that you control to make a copy of the content. Upload that copy, deleting it when the upload is complete. Those are problems regardless of this exception, and perhaps the exception will go away as well when you make these fixes.